# if else statement says " ',' or ')' expected"

Tags: python, if-statement

PyCharm says "invalid syntax" in line 8 (the else) at the back of that line it says " ',' or ')' expected"

At the back of line 9 it says "Statement expected found Py:COLON" and "Statement expected found Py:ELSE_KEYWORD"

Here my code using Python 3.9:

```
distance = " " + input("Please enter the distance the body is supposed to travel here, if unknow leave empty:  ")
speed = " " + input("Please enter the velocity of the body here, if unkown leave empty: ")
time = 0

def get_Time():
    if(distance == " " and speed == " "):
        time = int(input("Please enter the time required for the body to cover the distance: ")
    else:
        time = int(distance)/int(speed)
```

Dont realy know what to do to fix this. I don't even understand the problem.
Hope someone can help me.

Comment: You should consider closing the outer parenthesis here: `time = int(input("Please enter the time required for the body to cover the distance: ")`

Comment: Python is really bad at giving a useful error message when there is a mismatched parenthesis.

Comment: @Mark: Do. Or do not. There is no consider :-)

Comment: @Frank, that's because it's perfectly valid code to continue a statement on to the next line. The problem therefore is that you have an `else` inside your `int()` call, which is exactly what it's reporting. Perhaps a "statements should be on one line" optional flag in the compiler (or a linter) may be useful for these cases?

Comment: @paxdiablo.  I understand that.  But when it sees the "else" where it doesn't belong, perhaps saying "unexpected else inside a parenthesis" (or whatever the context happens to be) would be a lot clear.  There are a lot of questions identical to this one on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to put the closing parentheses at the line 8.
It should be like this:

```
time = int(input("Please enter the time required for the body to cover the distance: "))
```

That last parentheses was missing. That happens because you have casted the input to integer, and casting is: `type()`, and you did `type(`.

Answer (score 0):

the error is here:

```
time = int(input("Please enter the time required for the body to cover the distance: ")
```

open brackets twice.
close brackets only once.

need to close brackets twice.

```
time = int(input("Please enter the time required for the body to cover the distance: "))
```

Comment: it would help a lot more if you properly capitalised your sentences for grammar Nazis like me :-)

Comment: Presume you ment to start that comment with a capital... :-)